# Django- Get Current manage.py Command

Tags: django, django-admin

I Want To Know How Can Get Current manage.py Command.

For Example, When I syncdb In Shell, I Want To Get This Command Name.

How can I Do It?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Manage.py is just a python script: if you want to get the command passed to it in a script, it can be found in `sys.argv[1]`. Subsequent commands are further down the list: `sys.argv[0]` contains the name of the file executed (`manage.py` in your example); `sys.argv[1:]` has all parameters passed to the executed file.

Comment: This does not work when testing the commands because the executing command is `python manage.py test`. Does anyone know an alternative?

Answer (score -2):

Unless you have modified your file structure, manage.py always exists in the top-level directory of your project. If you are in the top-level directory, you can reference the script like this:

```
./manage.py
```